# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'xx'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'cc'. The duplicate key is (x)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

**Updated question for better understanding and because I found the solution, I was looking for:**

My script goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Columndata1] [nvarchar] (255) NOT NULL,
    [Columndata2] [nvarchar] (max) NOT NULL,
    [Columndata3] [nvarchar] (max) NOT NULL,
    [ColumndataTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Columndata1] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_ColumndataTime] DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [ColumndataTime]
GO
```

I am trying to do a workaround in case of duplicate PK, so that if it happens, it should ignore the request and if not create the table.

I guess I wasn't clear about it in my initial question.

Comment: dbo is usually a ms sql server schema not a mysql schema, a re you sure that you have m,ysql?

Comment: Sorry about that - the tags are hereby edited.

Comment: I assume `CREATE TEABLE` is a typo?

Comment: Where is your insert which is causing the error?

Comment: The error simply means your insert or update statement is creating a duplicate value in the `Columndata1` column. It's no more complicated than that.

Comment: @DaleK I will update my answer with more info.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yeah, that part I do get, but I don't understand why or better yet - how to prevent it.

Comment: Don't insert duplicate records. You're inserting or updating records so that duplicates appear. One reason for PK's to exist is to stop duplicates being inserted and you have specifically created one.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - for me it seems to be some kind of race condition issue and I wonder if I can avoid that somehow. It's easy to say "dont insert duplicate records".

Comment: What reason did you have to create a PK on `Columndata1`? It sounds like maybe you are learning as you go, which is _excellent_, far better than a lot of posts on here. To stop the immediate issue, remove the PK from the table. Then have a think about: is there anything in your data that uniquely identifies each row? If not the usual solution is to create an INT IDENTITY column to do it for you.

Comment: How is the value in `Columndata1` generated? Unless you have specific logic that ensures that it is unique, there's no reason to think it's unique

Comment: With a class like `MyRepo` are you saving data from a repo to a database? You need to work out if the source repo provides any kind of unique value you can use or whether you need to generate your own.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the `Columndata1` is explicitly a token, so in that sense I presume it must be unique, and thereby I also presume INT IDENTITY is not needed, right?

Comment: It's not unique if you're getting a PK error. If you turn off the PK you'll see the actual data it's putting in and be able to troubleshoot better. It might be writing multiple lines per token. Depends on how your class works

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ah okay, I presumed it couldn't be and therefore opt'ed that out. I guess I will have to add a new column (since the table is already created) and add the `IDENTITY` keyword to be sure on not getting any duplicates from now on. My initial thought was, that since it was a token, it couldn't be duplicated and a race condition instead was the problem.

Comment: If you designate the token as a unique value, but then write two rows with the same token, that's a duplicate. It depends on what your class is doing. It might be a race condition but there isn't enough code posted to come to that conclusion. It could be a trigger. It could be that the datatype you're using is truncating the token. It could be that a code bug that isn't setting the token properly, Take a look at the saved data. Or perhaps observe the error message and confirm that the full token value is in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution for it was to use the WHERE NOT EXISTS statement in SQL greatly inspired from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025332

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`value1`, `value2`) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` 
      WHERE `value1`='stuff for value1' AND `value2`='stuff for value2' LIMIT 1)
```

This way I won't get duplicates.

Kudos to Richard Hansell for the explanation, making me move my focus from the "complicated" part.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have your answer, you are inserting duplicate values to the column you designated as your primary key, the error you are getting tells you this, and it's all particularly clear. I can see that you assumed something more "sinister" was happening, but it seems to be that this wasn't the case, and it wasn't a "race condition" or something more complex.

However, I thought it might be worth pointing out something that I see as a bit of a "red flag". Maybe this doesn't classify as an answer, but it does address some points in your original question, particularly when you start asking about the options in the "complicated" part of your `CREATE TABLE` script, and it's too long for a comment?

If you have a "default" out of the box installation of SQL Server then 90% of the statements in your `CREATE TABLE` script are simply redundant defaults.

I can run this script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [Columndata1] [nvarchar] (255) NOT NULL,
    [Columndata2] [nvarchar] (max) NOT NULL,
    [Columndata3] [nvarchar] (max) NOT NULL,
    [ColumndataTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Columndata1]));
```

Then I can generate the create script for the table, directly from SSMS, to get this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Columndata1] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Columndata2] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Columndata3] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ColumndataTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Columndata1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

That second script looks very similar to the one in your post now doesn't it?

Now there's nothing necessarily wrong with specifying all of these default options, and there are cases where it might end up to your advantage, but my personal preference (and the preference of everyone I have ever worked with) is to omit the default options, as they just make scripts harder to peer review, and are essentially "clutter". You can argue over whether it's worth specifying the `ASC` in the `PRIMARY KEY` section or not, some of this is assumed knowledge, and there's always the possibility that Microsoft might decide to change defaults in the future (and then the first script wouldn't generate what you wanted). However, taking a pragmatic view of how these things work, the chances of Microsoft changing these options in a future version are incredibly slim, as it would break so many databases out there being used in the wild.

Take this as you want, but I thought it was worth a stab at explaining this, as you seem to be a little fixated (maybe the wrong word :)) on the "long part" (your words) in your original query?

Comment: Re-reading this, it comes over as a lot more "snarky" than I intended, so apologies for that, April 6th must have been a trying day for me :)

Comment: No it was perfect and moved my focus and thereby eventually found the correct answer. Thanks.